# no such table: (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

when i run my code (its for a project) i get this error: "no such table: encyclopedia_article". The error appears to come from 9 line of views.py (obj = article.objects.get(id=1). here is the code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import util
import random
from .models import article
from .forms import ArticleForm

def index(request):
    obj = article.objects.get(id=1)    #THIS IS WHAT APPERS TO CAUSE THE ERROR
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    entries = util.list_entries()
    random_page = random.choice(entries)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries(),
        "random_page": random_page,
    })
def CSS(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/css_tem.html", {
        "article_css": "css is slug and cat"
    })
def Python(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/python_tem.html", {
        "article_python": "python says repost if scav"
    })
def HTML(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/HTML_tem.html", {
        "article_HTML": "game theory: scavs are future humans"
    })
def Git(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/Git_tem.html", {
        "article_Git": "github is git"
    })
def Django(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/Django_tem.html", {
        "article_Django": "this is a framework"
    })
def new_article(request):
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/new_article_tem.html", context)
```

models.py:

```
class article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null = False)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import article
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = article
      fields = [
        'title',
        'description'
      ]
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("", views.CSS, name="CSS"),
    path("", views.Python, name="Python"),
    path("", views.HTML, name="HTML"),
    path("", views.Git, name="Git"),
    path("", views.Django, name="Django"),
    path("", views.new_article, name="new_article")
]
```

second urls (in other directory (there is encyclopedia and wiki this one is in wiki the last one in encyclopedia)):

```
"""wiki URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from encyclopedia import views
from encyclopedia.views import index
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls")),
    path('CSS/', views.CSS, name="CSS"),
    path('Python/', views.Python, name="Python"),
    path('HTML/', views.HTML, name="HTML"),
    path('Git/', views.Git, name="Git"),
    path('Django/', views.Django, name="Django"),
    path('new_article/', views.new_article, name="new_article"),
    path('main/', index)
]
```

new_article_tem.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    New Article
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Create Article</h1>
    <form method = 'POST' action = "{% url 'index' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
      
        <input type = 'submit' value='Save'>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

IM NOT SURE IF THIS ONES ARE USEFULL BUT STILL IM PUTTING ALMOST EVERYTHING:
index.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1 id="demo" onclick="add_article()">Add article</h1>


    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href = /{{entry}}>{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for article_title in created_articles %}
            <li>{{article_title}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li>{{title}}</li>
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

layout.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form>
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href = "/new_article" >Create New Article</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{random_page}}">Random Page</a>
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you make migrations and apply them?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this :-

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```